# python: copiar archivo y pegar un archivo el cual construyo el nombre mas la fecha de hoy

Tags: python

Tengo una carpeta donde diariamente se alojan reportes que van cambiando de nombre según la fecha. Por ejemplo:

Customer_Data_20221031.xlsx (creado el 31 de Octubre del 2022)
Customer_Data_20221030.xlsx (creado el 30 de Octubre del 2022)
Customer_Data_20221029.xlsx (creado el 29 de Octubre del 2022)
Customer_Data_20221028.xlsx (creado el 28 de Octubre del 2022)

Quiero copiar el ultimo archivo creado, de forma diaria y pegarlo en otra carpeta, es decir que Python busque el archivo más nuevo, lo copie y lo pegue en otra carpeta.

Entonces creo `datetime` un registro que concatene la palabra Customer_Data + la fecha de hoy, para luego decirle, con `shutil`, *copiame el archivo "Customer_Data + fecha de hoy.xlsx y pegalo en el directorio xxx*

Entonces:

```
  import datetime
  nombre_archivo = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
  Archivo = 'Customer_Data' + '_' + str(nombre_archivo) + '.xlsx'
  sourse = r"Z:\Customer Data\Archivo" #variable
  destination = r"Z:\Miguel\Documentacion Automate\Pipelines Automate\Credit Lines\Customer 
  Data.xlsx"
  shutil.copyfile(sourse, destination)
```

El problema es que no me toma la variable Archivo como directorio para copiarlo y pegarlo en destino.

¿Qué método podría usar para copiar el ultimo archivo creado dentro de una carpeta? o ¿Cómo puedo hacer que me tome la variable `Archivo` como parte del `path`?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar cambiando la variable archivo de esta forma:

```
Archivo = f'...\\Customer_Data_{nombre_archivo}.xlsx'
```

En el caso de que utilices Windows pon doble backslash ´\´ y donde están los puntos suspensivos completar con la ruta completa, por ejemplo:

```
Archivo = f'Z:\\Miguel\\Documentacion Automate\\Pipelines Automate\\...\\Customer_Data_{nombre_archivo}.xlsx'
```

Si quieres conservar ambar variables, `Archivo` y `destination`, yo probaría de la siguiente forma:

```
Archivo = f'Customer_Data_{nombre_archivo}.xlsx'
destination = f'Z:\\Miguel\\Documentacion Automate\\Pipelines Automate\\Credit Lines\\Customer\\{Archivo}'
```

Si con un backslash (`\`) funciona, puedes dejarlo como lo tenías.

Yo he utilizado `format` que es otra manera de concatenar string y que me resulta más simple visualmente ya que solamente pones entre llaves las variables que necesites.

Comment: Para agregar a tu respuesta, si no queres preocuparte por, por ejemplo, el caracter usado para separar directorios, podes usar el modulo de la libreria estandar pathlib.